# Cubes, what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am a cube
> Made up of cubes
> Twenty six cubes
> Colorful cubes
> Spinning cubes
> Sliding cubes
> But always a cube
> A large, cubed cube
> Not a ruby cube
> And not a phoenix cube
> But a bright cube
> With-lot's-of-colors cube

What kind of cube am I?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's straightforward description and not really puzzly.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you are a

> Rubik's cube.

Most of the description is obvious but maybe it's worth pointing out that

> "ruby cube" and "phoenix cube" are clearly chosen as sounding a bit like "Rubik's cube".

I have to say that this feels to me rather too straightforward for a *riddle*.